# Recyclerview touch events

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is the first time I am working with `RecyclerView`, I have made `Adapter` class with some static mock data.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view){

            super(view);

            textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.MyTextView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent ,false);

        Toast.makeText(context, "@@@@@@@@@@@@" +viewType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        viewHolder1 = new ViewHolder(view1);

        return viewHolder1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(SubjectValues[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return SubjectValues.length;
    }
}
```

this is my `Adapter` clas now it's showing the mock data I want to achieve the click event.

Comment: Is your data showing properly ? Where did you set the adapter , please share that code ?

Comment: as a begginer better try  some tutorials,http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 4):

In Adapter class, inside onBindViewHolder() method, you can register listener to the whole row as the following :

```
vh1.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Toast.makeText(ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter.this, "Item no: "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "General click !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If you want to register listener to a specific view inside a row layout, you can do it as the following :

```
vh1.getButton().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Toast.makeText(ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter.this, "Item no: "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button is clicked ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

The whole source code for the adapter class :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case USER:
            ViewHolder1 vh1 = (ViewHolder1) viewHolder;
            configureViewHolder1(vh1, position);
            break;
    }
}

private void configureViewHolder1(ViewHolder1 vh1, int position) {
    User user = (User) items.get(position);
    if (user != null) {
        vh1.getLabel1().setText("Name: " + user.name);
        vh1.getLabel2().setText("Hometown: " + user.hometown);

        vh1.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Toast.makeText(ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter.this, "Item no: "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "General click !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        vh1.getButton().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Toast.makeText(ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter.this, "Item no: "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button is clicked ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ViewHolder1.java

```
public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView label1, label2;

    private Button button;

    public ViewHolder1(View v) {
        super(v);
        ...
        button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }

    public void setButton(Button button) {
        this.button = button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your onBindViewHolder set OnClickListener

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final HomeListAdapter.MainViewHolder homeViewHolder, final int position) {

        homeViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item no: "+ position, LENGTH_SHORT).show;
            }
        });
}
```

Using this way will make items layout clickable not only a textview or button.
If perticularly you want to give action on click of button or textveiew then you can use reference of those components e.g.
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClick..)......

Answer (score 0):

To add a click event add the following into the onBindViewHolder method:

```
holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int adapterPos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                    if(adapterPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, SubjectValues[adapterPos], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
        });
```

That would add a click listener to the textView which shows a toast of the value.
Note: I have made assumptions on what your SubjectValues is, as not included in your question.

But the important things to observe here are:

- holder.getAdapterPosition()
- Check position (!= RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
- Set this in onBindViewHolder

I believe this is a fair summary of how to set a click listener within a recyclerview adapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, but one thing need to say, why we need a position if already have a position in 
`onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position)`

Comment: In some cases the position in the ```onBindViewHolder``` would work, but I don't think that it is the correct way. As items positions in your adapter can change after you have set the click listener, either because they have been removed or moved (usually user interaction). Either way, I strongly recommend using ```holder.getAdapterPosition()``` as it gives a better, more future proof solution. Certainly from my experience it can mean a lot less time chasing a bug that isn't immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

add this class to your project

```
public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}}
```

then in your RecyclerView use this

```
    myRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            YourModel model = modelList.get(position);
      }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnItemClickListener` interface into your adapter.

```
OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(
        final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}
```

Implements `OnItemClickListener` on `ViewHolder` like below.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.MyTextView);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mItemClickListener != null) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }       
}
```

In your Activity or Fragment `setOnItemClickListener` on your adapter.

```
 mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
          // Do your stuff here when item clicked
        }
    });
```